# Use Index on Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, cloudera

I am using Hive 0.12. I have created a couple of index for my table.
Now, how can I tell Hive to use those?
At the moment, I am just writing:

```
set hive.optimize.autoindex=true;
set hive.optimize.index.filter = true;
```

Is that ok, or I need to add further stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Depending of the kind of query you're running, indexes are *automatically* used by the Hive query rewrite engine.

Specifically, you may see a performance improvement on queries using the index fields in :
- where clause
- group by clause
- aggregation clause

If you're using a "smart" SerDe like Parquet or ORCFile, can you tell me if you see a performance gap between manual indexing and using the SerDe files metadata ?

Answer (score -1):

As with most DBMS you need to manually create the indexs by specifying the name, the columns and the type.

There are very useful examples Hive's official documentation here:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Indexing